# c# Transfer file from remote machine to terminal server

Tags: c#, terminal-services

I am creating an app that will be used with terminal services, and I have created a explorer that will allow me to  transfer files. this is first of all only on local machine. Is there a way that will allow me to connect to the remote machine access their common library. that would allow them to choose desktop and Documents folders.
I have been trying to get the IP address of the remote machine by [Code Projects Grabbing Information Of Terminal Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111430/Grabbing-Information-of-a-Terminal-Services-Sessio). I guess I'm really at a loss of words here, I'm not sure where to begin to start this process. any help or Ideas links would be very helpful.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your file? In the net folder, or not? Can you install serviceses on target machine?
You can use Process.Start method in combination with Mark Russinovich utilities or powershell remoting.

Comment: The file could be anywhere on their machine. This app will have an UI that I would like for them to have a file explorer that will allow them to open the file that they wish to transfer. All of the computers that will be remoting in will be inside the domain.

Comment: Can you install services on remote machines? If yes: 
create service, that will contain methods like FilesInCatalog(string path):string[], GetSubfoldersInCatalog(string path):string[], GetFile(string path):byte[]; 
install that services to target machines;
add some security;
invoke this services from the central machines.

If no, use PS-remoting or Mark Russinovich utilities with combination of Process.Start(). You'll need to read an output from the process, i think.

First variant is easier.